# Solve the Closest Pair Algorithm with recursion(Divide and Conquer)

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I understand how to solve the infamous "Closest Pair Problem" using brute force, but what about a simple algorithm in O(n^2) running time that might work recursively? The problem is

`Given a set of n points, write the code to find the closest pair of points`

What is a simple recursive function that can be used to solve this problem?

Here's a test problem, where the first number is the number of points and the following lines contain the points themselves:

```
6
0 5
1 13
5 9
1 8
3 10
6 10
```

Comment: What did you try?  Google directs me to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem and I'm not going to do better than that...

Comment: I disagree with the premise that an *O(n^2)* recursive solution is somehow simpler/better than an *O(n^2)* nested loop solution.

Comment: Sorry I need to restate the problem. I would like to see how the problem is solved recursively, whether it is simpler/better is subjective.

Comment: actually the recursive solution *is* better as it can run in O(nlogn), as with every recursive solution you divide the problem into smaller ones (into how many would you dived them) and then try to merge the results (is there anything you need to do during the merge?)

Comment: No, there shouldn't be? Not sure if that was a rhetorical question.. I do know that an answer is provided here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closest-pair_problem but I was hoping for something easier to read and see how it actually works.

Comment: @Chisx btilly pointed you to the wiki page where you can check the "Planar case" section

Comment: Thank you Mateusz Dymczyk, that does make good sense, I was just wondering if someone would show me what that looks like in code. Sorry if this sounds lame but I cannot conceive of how one might write this in C# in the simplest way possible.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's step 4 (of wikipedia's planar case) that makes the code look messy. But if you remove step 4 (using a naive *O(n^2)* algorithm for that step), then the algorithm is just a very complicated *O(n^2)* solution. In other words, there is no simple recursive code, because step 4 is, by necessity, messy.

Answer (score 2):

This code finds the nearest pair of points of A using divide and conquer, and runs in O(N^2) time. The efficient algorithm (which you're trying to understand) replaces part which starts with "for left in pL": instead of comparing every pair of points from the left and right sides, it compares at most 6 points from the right side for every point on the left.

The `closest` function here returns the distance squared of the nearest pair as well as the pair of points. That's convenient for taking `min`s.

```
import itertools

def dist2(a, b):
    return (a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2

def closest(A):
    if len(A) <= 3:
        return min((dist2(a, b), (a, b)) for a, b in itertools.combinations(A, 2))
    pL = A[:len(A)//2]
    pR = A[len(A)//2:]
    result = min(closest(pL), closest(pR))
    for left in pL:
        for right in pR:
            result = min(result, (dist2(left, right), (left, right)))
    return result

test = [map(float, x.split(' ')) for x in '0 5,1 13,5 9,1 8,3 10,6 10'.split(',')]
print closest(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the problem could be solved recursively using C#

```
double diffL, diffR;
List<double> L, R;
int mid;

public static double DnQ(List<double> P)
{
     if(P.Length == 2)  //base case
          return P[0]-P[1];

     mid = P.Length/2;  //calculate middle of List of points
     L = P.GetRange(0, mid);
     R = P.GetRange(mid+1,P.Length - mid);

     diffL = DnQ(L); //recursive call on left side
     diffR = DnQ(R); //recursive call on right side

     if(diffL > diffR)  //return differences
          return diffR;
     else
          return diffL;
}
```

Comment: Good job, is it working?  I think maybe R should be P.GetRange(mid+1,P.Length-1)

Comment: The algorithm you copied from the other question isn't correct.